# How to orderBy with count function for a single colmn in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column which shows the number of total referrals a user have.
Below is my code. I want to paginate order by the person have highest number of refs. I tried with `max('totalref')` but then `paginate` not works.
So I am confused with this type of alignment

```
public function leaders()
{

    $accounts = Account::Where('totalref','>' , 5)->orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(200);
    return view('admin.leaders', compact('accounts'));
}
```

Comment: $accounts = Account::Where('totalref','>' , 5)->orderBy('totalref','DESC')->paginate(200);

Comment: it aligns like all number with 9 first , then with first already tried

Answer (score 1):

When you are working with paginated data, you want to do ordering, searching and etc. in the query. As based on your comment, it seems like totalref is a string in your database, convert it to an integer and the following will work.

```
$accounts = Account::Where('totalref','>' , 5)->orderBy('totalref','desc')->paginate(200);
```

Comment: i tried it already orderBy('totalref','desc'). it shows values with satrting with 9 first then 8 then 7 etc

Comment: And if you read the answer it seems like you are sorting on strings,  so what data type is total ref?

Comment: agree with @MartinHenriksen, double check `totalref` column type.